# Blocking Canvas

Tags: delphi, canvas, bitmap, firemonkey

I have a form of my app that can have up to 1000 visual components, in which I draw each one once using Canvas of a bitmap, and save this bitmap of each component (a kind of double buffered), because each operation takes 20 ms.

I'm using threads to paint the bitmaps and send notifications with this bitmap to the MainThread, to refresh the visual components, the UI.

Theoretically, it would have to have a fluid form opening with the components being displayed as their bitmaps were painted in the threads, but in practice it was not fluid. I decided to take a look at the delphi's TCanvas and I noticed something staggering:

```
class var // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< class var
  FLock: TObject;

function TCanvas.BeginScene(AClipRects: PClipRects = nil; AContextHandle: THandle = 0): Boolean;
begin
  Lock;
  ...
end;

procedure TCanvas.EndScene;
begin
  ...
  Unlock;
end;

class procedure TCanvas.Lock;
begin
  TMonitor.Enter(FLock);
end;

class procedure TCanvas.Unlock;
begin
  TMonitor.Exit(FLock);
end;
```

This definitely does not seem right. Why does the embarcadero make it impossible to work with TCanvas simultaneously in different threads? It's no use creating 10 threads to be doing bitmap drawings since everything will be processed 1 at a time...

1. Why does this exist?
2. Is there any workaround? What can happen if I make my version of
   FMX.Graphics with only local monitors for each TCanvas?
3. Is there any third party lib with it own TCanvas?

I know that many will advise me to use native classes, JCanvas in android and CGContextRef in iOS, but I wanted a solution with TCanvas, because its job is to be a wrapper for drawing functions of all platforms, and to be easy to use.

=============  @EDIT  =============

I changed the Lock and Unlock of the TCanvas in the FMX.Graphics unit to use local instead of global monitors, as well as the BeginScene and EndScene of TContext3D in the FMX.Types3D unit.
I'm very apprehensive about this change but apparently the app is working normal, the biggest job was recompile the entire FMX.

Comment: Prepare to be disappointed. Also, thousands of visual components is a bad sign. That can't be the best approach. I'd bet that the problem could be solved readily without why threading at all.

Comment: Especially in Firemonkey on mobile platforms, it's very poor design to have too many controls. It becomes too heavy. Instead, you should a) Re-use controls as much as possible, b) Make separate forms for separate topics and only create them the first time needed, and c) Destroy controls when they're no longer needed.

Comment: @JerryDodge I am displaying cards of products, that is inside an vertscrollbox. I've already reduced the number of controls, making just "displayer controls" that its bitmap buffer have many product cards... Unfortunately I can't create just one "big display control" because the canvas have an size limit for each device (TCanvasAttribute.MaxBitmapSize). But it's not the question. All major mobile apps use many threads to decode jpegs, draw buffers, etc., just to save the MainThread and to allow a quick form opening and not compromise the minimum 60 fps to make the screen fluid.

Comment: Is the user able to display all of these product cards at once? If not, there is no reason to draw them - and you draw all of them, if I understand correctly? - all at once, but determine which are visible, and then draw these.Maybe even have thumbnails for the overview and only have the full product image in a detail view?

Answer (score 1):

Tbitmap is not really multithread. It's was made as multithread in Delphi Tokyo but with a very poor design (their is still many bug when you use Tbitmap in background thread, for example Tbitmap still use messaging notification that are not multithread at all and thus can result in random exception). What was done not bad in tokyo is to make the OpenGL context multithread (under android/ios), and that work quite well (but not the TTexture that are still bounds to Messaging, but you can easily update the source code of ttexture to correct it (You can look the source code of [Alcinoe](https://github.com/Zeus64/alcinoe) to know how to do it).

The only workaround for what you want to achieve is :

1. Don't use TBitmap but use instead Texture (because openGL Fully multithread without any lock)
2. Build the texture in background thread with native OS function (JCanvas in android and CGContextRef in iOS)
3. Avoid to use so many controls, but instead paint yourself all the texture that are ready and visible from the main thread (so in an onpaint event) at the right place

Yes I know it's a pain!

Comment: Yes, I already use your lib, alcinoe, I really like it and I see that you use native functions. It's too much work, but it works fine. But I belieave that It's not very difficult to create a custom bitmap written from scratch, done the right way, with a custom Canvas that is a wrapper for this natives functions, multiplatform, multithread, with local critical sections, and that have a texture property... And then create a helper to TCanvas of the controls draw this custom bitmap...

Comment: "Avoid to use so many controls" Yes, I already use the minimum controls whenever possible, and the performance is very good, the problem is just the first draw, that is why I had to paint in background threads.

Comment: @vfbb you can try to go with Tcanvas (that work directly on the openGL), but at the end you will see that the embarcadero team can not compet the job made by the thousands of android developpers in the Jcanvas or the ios developper in their graphic function. If speed and quality (yes quality is also a factor) is not very matter then try to go with Tbitmap (but not in multithread)